# Align elements of layout in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

i'm new in ORACLE ADF FUSION MIDDLEWARE so i'm not experienced in form designing.
Can anyone help me with aligning some elements in layout.

I want to align ORACLE logo ALWAYS to the right. If window resolution is decreased so the logo is  NOT moving. Logo should always be in right edge of window.

I'm using PanelGroupLayout.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- In the Panel Group Layout make halign = **right**
- In the Panel Group Layout make layout = **vertical**
- In the Panel Group Layout make styleClass = **AFStretchWidth**

That's it

Comment: I guess styleClass = AFStretchWidth ain't necessary, since layout vertical will create DIV layout and thus will take all available width, beside the case where you have more than one div in the same row.

Comment: The AFStretchWidth because I'm not sure what is the Panel Group Layout's parent component if the parent component doesn't stretch it's children. But you are right in this case it might not be needed.